# Stock availability is disabled

Tags: magento2, stock, inventory

I have a configurable product with 1 "child" product.

On "child" product Inventory, I only have 1 product for Qty, and the Stock availability became "out of Stock".

Now I just change the qty value to 10000, and Stock availability continues as "out of Stock" and this dropdown is disabled and I can not change this value.

I was "digging" on the code, and I found that is the configurable-type-handler.js that check if product is configurable or not, if not, the dropdown changes to disabled.

How can user change stock availability for "child" products?

Thank you

Comment: This child product also avilable in magento admin grid. You can change for child product from grid.